# Como hacer que git incluya un .git

Tags: git

Buenas, estoy en linux, y por alguna razon quiero hacerle un backup con git a todo lo que me interese, algunos ficheros de configuracion y algunos proyectos en los que estoy trabajando, que estos proyectos usan git.

El problema es que al tratar de versionar las carpetas de los proyectos, git los coge como subproycetos, y solo coge la referencia al ultimo commit del proyecto. cuando quiero que versione todas las carpetas, incluyendo el `.git`

No se si esto es posible en git, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida

Comment: Esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18330114/5622844) te puede ayudar. :)

Comment: revise el post, me parecio que la parte de `[include]
  path = ../.gitconfig` iba por el buen camino pero no logro que funcione, pensaba en `[include] path = ./project/.git/*`

Answer (score 1):

Podrias pensar en usar submodulos y tener un repo de tipo personal/projects asi podrias tenerlos versionados, todos agrupados en una única carpeta pero cada proyecto tendría su repositorio independiente.

https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/